# Space de-limited results, errors when Concatenating 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

the code I'm running gives results that are space de-liminated. This creates a problem with my sector column which gives a result of Communication Services. It creates 1 column for Communication and another column for Services where I need 1 column saying Communication Services. I have tried to concatentate the 2 columns into 1 but I'm getting attribute and str errors and don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone show how this can be done? Thanks

Code

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

list_of_futures= []

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    s= f"{ticker} {info['currentPrice']} {info['marketCap']} {info['sector']}"
    
    list_of_futures.append(s)

ticker_list = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'GTBIF', 'META']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(get_stats, ticker_list)
    
(
    pd.DataFrame(list_of_futures)
        [0].str.split(expand=True)
        .rename(columns={0: "Ticker", 1: "Price", 2: "Market Cap", 3: "Sector", 4: "Sector1"})
        .to_excel("yahoo_futures.xlsx", index=False)
)
```

Current Results

[image]

Desired Results

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us reformulate the `get_stats` function to return dictionary instead string. This way you can avoid the unnecessary step to `split` the strings to create a dataframe

```
def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    cols = ['currentPrice', 'marketCap', 'sector']
    return {'ticker': ticker, **{c: info[c] for c in cols}}

tickers = ['AAPL', 'ORCL', 'GTBIF', 'META']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result_iter = executor.map(get_stats, tickers)

df = pd.DataFrame(result_iter)
```

Result

```
  ticker  currentPrice      marketCap                  sector
0   AAPL        148.11  2356148699136              Technology
1   ORCL         82.72   223027183616              Technology
2  GTBIF         13.25     3190864896              Healthcare
3   META        111.41   295409188864  Communication Services
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to get rid of that first column where it says 0 1 2 3?

Comment: @user3444610 That's not an column. Its an index :-) While saving to csv you can get rid of it by passing the optional parameter `index=False` in `to_excel` method